# Test-charge injection circuit for CSA(Charge Sensitive Amplifier) in CMOS IC

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, cmos

I need to inject test-charge (electrons) into a CSA.
Is there any specific name for this kind of circuit?
Is there any other alternative for the circuit below?

This is one of the example.
This circuit inject current in some part of the reset-inject cycle, which is unwanted.
Ideally, I expect a circuit that suck the current out of the CSA input.

[image]

Comment: Current multiplied by time is charge so, no specific name just a flow of current and something that gates it with respect to time.

Comment: What is the magnitude of the test charge to be injected? What precision do you require (% error.) How will you calibrate it for accuracy? And are you aware that FETs inject and remove charge when switched and NOT in a controlled way?

Comment: @jonk around 300 electrons. as accurate as the area allowed. The area is very limited, <20 um2, so the number of components must be limited. it will not be calibrated. yes, I am aware.

Comment: @Codelearner777 So, 48 attoCoulombs?

Comment: @jonk yes, around that value.

Comment: @Codelearner777 I worked on a system where my detectability was at about 400-600 attoCoulombs. I was at a point where I was able to observe photon flocking effects, then. I think you are well outside my experience. And you seriously expect to use *discrete* FETs to gate the charge injection?

Comment: @jonk No, I am implementing it as integrated circuit, not discrete components on PCB.

Comment: @Codelearner777 From past experience working with IC designers at Burr Brown, charge injection of IC fets are on the order of whole picoCoulombs. And without trimming, the variability is rather high. You need to work with the FAB folks, I think.